# this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90

Tags: c

stackoverflowers :> (Can i say that? :| ) 
OK... this time i want to know if this warning should be solved, or should be ignored.
It represent the number of experience needed for advancing at next level. (for a game)
This is the error: `warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90`
And this is the file: ( I will show just a part of the code, it is pretty much long :D.)

```
const DWORD exp_table_common[PLAYER_EXP_TABLE_MAX + 1] =
{

2150000000, //  100
2210000000,     
2250000000,     
2280000000,     
2310000000,     
2330000000, //  105
2350000000,     
2370000000,     
2390000000,     
2400000000,     
2410000000, //  110
2420000000,     
2430000000,     
2440000000,     
2450000000,     
2460000000, //  115
2470000000,     
2480000000,     
2490000000,     
2490000000,     
2500000000, //  120
};
```

This are just the warned rows.

Comment: put a `U` suffix on them to mark them as unsigned

Answer (score 3):

In C90, a decimal constant gets the type it first fits into

```
int, long, unsigned long
```

In C99 onward, a decimal constant gets the type it first fits into

```
int, long, long long
```

In your system, `2150000000` is bigger than `LONG_MAX` (certainly 2147483647).  So with a C90 compiler, it is `unsigned long`.  With current compilers, it is `long long`.

Should you ignore?  It depends on subsequent code.  Recommended to not ignore and explicitly declaring the decimal constant as an unsigned one by appending the `u` suffix like `2500000000u`.

Comment: Interesting. Can one speculate about the reasons for this change? As, on a glance, it *seems* an unecessary complication. (But good to hear there is a perfectly acceptable general solution.)

Comment: @Jongware IDK.  [Here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/c1.html#3-1-3-2) and [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) may help. Maybe better to warning of a decimal constant over `LLONG_MAX` than proceed without warning.

Comment: It should be noted that C compilers that had a `long long` type before they implemented C99 put `long long` at the end of the list. GCC, for instance, tries by default to type unsuffixed decimal constants with the list `int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long` (but this list is changed to the “normal” `int, long, long long` if you use the commandline option -std=c99)

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq  Nice comment.  For a _long_ time, I thought it was what it is now for octal and hexadecimal constant: `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long`.  Now older and a bit wiser.

Comment: @chux Interestingly, what you thought is also exactly what the implementers of the front-end library used by the static analyzer I spent so much time on thought. With an ILP32 compiler, the two are difficult to distinguish. See the damning (incorrect) comment and code at https://github.com/kerneis/cil/blob/9435520d8984c47376cb10a85ede450e40b4d290/src/cil.ml#L2588